# how to develop mobile app supported with all platforms

Tags: mobile

> I have new app as a game . the game about home and products as TV Refrigerator LCD ..etc. so use can drag the product at the room on your home as if you are preparing your new home but this will be as a game and when user finished from completing his home he will like and share this on Facebook . this game will be **app** supported with all **mobile platforms** .So how can I do this solution I know java but I cannot imagine how can I do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest answer is to write a web app. Every modern mobile device (probably) has a web browser. Two options for this: (I'm sure you can find dozens of tutorials on either)

- Have your app sit somewhere on a website. Not too difficult once you have a website.
- Deploy an executable. Try Googling something like "how to deploy an html5 executable". [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504651/pack-an-html5-app-and-deploy-it-on-the-desktop) looks like it may help.

If every required mobile device has a JVM (which I'll bet they don't), then you can write a single Java app that will work on all the devices.

There are programs designed specifically for this purpose, though I don't have the name of one on hand.

Comment: what about if I used HTML5 and CSS on creating this game ?

Comment: @Egydeveloper That could work, though HTML5 may not be supported by older mobile devices.

Comment: Thanks Dukeling , I hope if you sent me an example ,I searched more but  I lost:)

Comment: @Egydeveloper See edit. For any more complex answer, I'd probably basically just be Googling and giving you the results.