# bundle HTML files into a one click windows executable

Tags: javascript, html, chm

I have a site which contains a set of HTMLs, linked to each other.

I want to deliver this in a windows executable, where all the files will be wrapped in to a .exe (or any other) file  when clicked will render the index.html in a browser, and a user can view

the behaviour i am seeking for is something like the CHM files

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Compiled_HTML_Help

whats the best way of making this ?

Comment: Not with Javascript, server side language would be preferable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pack an HTML5 app and deploy it on the desktop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504651/pack-an-html5-app-and-deploy-it-on-the-desktop) or [HTML5 for desktop application development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869613/html5-for-desktop-application-development)

Comment: cant use CHM as this needs to look like an app, but i think the HTML 5 app and deploy on desktop is the way to go thanks