# JavaScript standalone game?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a desktop game in JavaScript, but I don't know how to make it run in it's own window from an exe file just like a normal game. I see only JavaScript games running in browser. I want to know if it is possible (and how if it is) to make a standalone JavaScript game on desktop that doesn't need either internet connection nor browser to run, just an exe from which the game will be started.

Comment: chrome packaged apps, adobe air, node-webkit, HTA, Chrome application shortcut, etc... don't listen to naysayers, it's possible, even easy. node-webkit is probably the best going forward because it creates not only EXEs, but linux, mac, and mobile apps as well...

Comment: [possibly this blog post too (admittedly rather old by this point)](http://www.phpied.com/make-your-javascript-a-windows-exe/)

Comment: @dandavis: you should post this as an answer

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504651/pack-an-html5-app-and-deploy-it-on-the-desktop

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in an initial comment by @dandavis there are many different ways of going about making a local application using javascript. The best I can suggest is to do some research and discover a platform that works best for your needs.

I am [including a link](https://brainhub.eu/blog/javascript-frameworks-for-desktop-apps/) to help you get started down that path.
Good luck, and happy scripting!

Comment: Besides that the question is five years old, and requests for frameworks/libraries/etc are explicitly off-topic, link-only answers are also considered inappropriate.